# What is a good resource to learn dialogue mixing?

Tags: post-production, film-sound-design, film-mixing, film-school

I am constantly making short films, and I want to improve my post-production audio, specifically dialogue mixing.

I'm not sure if that's the correct term, so specifically, I want to learn how to identify and fix problems with recorded dialogue tracks.

I am looking for a resource (ideally) aimed at a beginner, but covering the topic to the level of detail required of someone working on a film/television production.

I have not successfully found such a resource using Google. YouTube tutorials tend to lack comprehensiveness (e.g. they introduce you to a topic such as de-noising, but try to present a one-click solution, they don't teach you how to tweak the parameters to get a better result, or focus on the tools rather than provide an understanding of what constitutes a good result)

Advanced resources, such as forum posts, tend to be decentralized and addressed at people with moderate to advanced understandings of the topic, and I have trouble understanding these because my skill level and vocabulary is low.

Another big issue is that I don't know what I don't know. Again, comprehensiveness is key.

My ideal tutorial is this series: https://www.provideocoalition.com/advanced-keying-with-after-effects-part-1/ which covers chroma keying in After Effects. I am looking for tutorials like this, but for de-essing, de-noising, EQ, LUFS, and whatever other skill that someone mixing dialogue should understand. Ideally written for REAPER, but if I absolutely positively should be using a different DAW for this task, I would switch.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before mixing, you need to learn Dialogue Editing.

A good reference Dialogue Editing resource is the book by Purcell "Dialogue Editing for Motion Pictures". Bit dated in terms of the technology, but the principles are sound and lasting.

Comment: Thank you, this is a satisfactory answer